# Artifactory - Cancel operation in plugin - How to inform the user about what was wrong?

Tags: plugins, artifactory

I successfully implemented a plugin for Artifactory which prevent any user to delete/overwrite any artifact that he has not created. This was done thanks to the "storage" hook and by implementing the appropriate "beforeCreate"/"beforeDelete" closures mentioned here:

[Artifactory - user plugins](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins#UserPlugins-Storage)

My problem is that if you cancel an operation, the only thing that the user see in the popup displayed by Artifactory is that "Undeploy was cancelled by a user plugin". How have the screenshot below:

[How Artifactory notifies users when an action is cancelled by a plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKDXI.png)

**Is there anyway to have a more relevant status displayed by this popup?**

Cheers
JM

Answer (score 1):

To start with a small disclosure, I'm with JFrog (:

The CancelException is the right way to go but currently not all closures support this functionality.
For example in the following user plugin deploying and deleting of any file will be blocked.

```
import org.artifactory.exception.CancelException

storage {
    beforeDelete { item ->

        throw new CancelException("This cannot happen", 403)
    }

    beforeCreate { item ->

        throw new CancelException("This cannot happen", 403)
    }
}
```

However only the *beforeDeploy* closure will display the customer error message to the user when trying to deploy an artifact from the UI.

We have opened the following two improvements related to the issue you raised here. Feel free to watch the issues in order to get a notification once it will be resolved.

[RTFACT-13829](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-13829) |
[RTFACT-13828](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-13828)

[image]